# How do I have different paperclip paths set depending on whether in development or production in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I am using Heroku for my production environment so I need to load the paperclip files into different directories.

For development I want it to continue in the current /system default, and in production I want to pass the :path variable to a /tmp directory per Heroku.

How do I do this?  Am guessing maybe set something in the environments/production.rb file as a variable for the :path but I'd like to see explicitly how to do it the right way.

Thanks.

Here is a snippet from my controller to create the model after passing the file through a multipart form:

```
def create
    @contact = Contact.create(params[:contact])

     unless @contact.vcard.path.blank?

           paperclip_vcard = File.new(@contact.vcard.path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model holding the attached file there's a method you say it holds that file and some options, etc. In that method you can pass the `:path` parameter that will tell it where to save it.

Now is just a matter of  checking `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to find out what environment you are and set the path accordingly.

Comment: Hi, where do I pass the parameter.  Here is from the create controller:

def create
    @contact = Contact.create(params[:contact])

     unless @contact.vcard.path.blank?
    
           paperclip_vcard = File.new(@contact.vcard.path) 

It seems like after the multipart form upload, it gets attached when creating the model instance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Heroku does not support storing application generated files on their servers (read-only) so for your production environment you will have to find some external (to Heroku) storage solution. They have provided details on how to use Amazon's S3 service [here](http://docs.heroku.com/s3) by way of an example on how to do this.